# 500 - Internal Server Error during Spotify's Client Credentials Authentication flow

Tags: authentication, spotify

I'm attempting to authenticate my application using Spotify's web API Client Credentials Authorization flow, but despite the seemingly simple task, every response I've gotten has returned a 500 - Internal Server Error.

I've attempted many times in both cURL and within my application (Android) to no avail. Following the guides here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow

I've set up my cURL as such

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Basic ODZiMDJ...MWI=' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
```

The request is structured with identical headers, body, and URL in the code as well, but I have yet to receive any valid responses.

Another question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044062/spotify-webapi-authorization-client-credentials-flow-error-invalid-client) gives a seemingly identical request, aside from the optional "Scope" parameter.

My apologies if this seems like a vague question - I'm not sure what else to try, but I'd be more than happy to provide any additional details. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looking at https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow   Step 1,2,3 went okey?

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, unless I am mistaken, each authentication flow is independent. I'm trying to implement the second option, using Client Credentials. I believe you are referring to steps 1, 2, and 3 of the first method.

Comment: I have just tried this with my own client_id and client_secret and it works. You could try cloning https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples, adding your credentials in the client_credentials/app.js and try it out. And even if there is something wrong in your request, you shouldn't get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

code and redirect_uri  body parameters are required according to documentation